# Authenticate in Django without a database

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-authentication

I have a Django app that gets it's data completely from apis. so I don't have to use database. Session data is stored on signed cookies. I tried to code a custom User model and a custom auth backend like on the docs, but I get the following error:
`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'my_app.MyUser' that has not been installed`

My settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'my_app.MyUser'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
                           'my_app.backends.LoginAuthBackend',)
```

models.py:

```
class MyUser(object):
    def save(self):
        pass
    objects = None
    username = ""
```

Here, If a try use the AbstractUser from django instead of Object I got the following error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'` or the db table doesn't exit.

backends.py

```
class LoginAuthBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        if username and password:
           try:
               response = my_auth_function(username, password)
               if response.status_code == 200:
                   token = response.get('my_key')
                   user = MyUser()
                   return user
            except MyCustomException:
                  return None
```

It's drives me crazy. Looks like Django that's not easy to use without a DB.

### EDIT

After several of tries, a simple way to solve this is remove  `'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'` from `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` and  `AUTH_USER_MODEL` from settings. The model continues basically the same way. works smoothly

Comment: Yes, Django is very dependent on database. It was designed this way. It looks like Django authentication system really wants you to have a User model and will not work without one. You could try harder to fool Django into accepting a fake model, but you would have to implement a whole bunch of interfaces specific to model instances and querysets.

Answer (score 4):

The default set of authentication back-end processors is defined in the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting. See the Django documentation for [Customizing authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/).

> By default, AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS is set to:
>
> ```
> ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
> ```
>
> That’s the basic authentication backend that checks the Django users database and queries the built-in permissions.

So, if you don't want the `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` authentication method, remove that from the list. You'll probably want to find (or create) a different one and add that to the list.